# Need help to resolve this indentation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Person:
      def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    p1 = Person("John", 36)

    print(p1.name)
    print(p1.age)
```

SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

I am a newbie in Python programming. Can you help me resolve this error?

Comment: In python your indentation should be four spaces deep. The second line of your code is indented 6 spaces.

Comment: If you're a newbie consider using and ide such as Pycharm or Spyder, or atleast a good editor like vscode. These ide/editors will automatically catch syntax errors and help you accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Things from that `p1 =` line forward should be fully unindented. The usual Python style is 4 spaces per indentation level; here's your code fixed with the Black formatter:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Comment: can u share from where to download black for windows?

Comment: It's a Pip package, so you can install it with `pip install black`. For quick ad-hoc formatting, I use my own service https://nicen.pw/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

I think you wanted to define `__init__` magic method instead of `init` .

Comment: Running on IDLE getting this error after running above codeclass Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


    p1 = Person("John", 36)

    print(p1.name)
    print(p1.age)

    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    class Person:
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 7, in Person
    p1 = Person("John", 36)
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
>>>

Comment: What is the error? Can you explain please? I've checked it and it works for me.

Comment: Running it in IDLE & getting this error:NameError: name 'Person' is not defined >>>